# Order by value of array multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like this

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'document_id' => string '231' (length=3)
          'document_title' => string 'Renstra 2014-2018 Distamben COVER' (length=33)
          'document_date' => string '2014-10-15 14:09:00' (length=19)
          'site' => string 'Propinsi Nusa Tenggara Barat' (length=28)
          'url_download' => string 'http://ntbprov.sip-ppid.net/index.php/document/download/231' (length=59)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=5)
          'document_id' => string '7' (length=1)
          'document_title' => string 'Data Menara 2014' (length=16)
          'document_date' => string '2015-01-08 13:05:00' (length=19)
          'site' => string 'Kabupaten Bima' (length=14)
          'url_download' => string 'http://bimakab.sip-ppid.net/index.php/document/download/7' (length=57)
```

how to sort by document_date? I try with usort() but not working.
I am Newbie.

Comment: Show your `usort()` attempt. Also where are you getting this array? If from a db, why not order it in your query

Comment: Have looked at/tried examples #2 & #4 at http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php?

Comment: my usort() function date_compare($a, $b) {
        $t1 = max(strtotime($a[0]), strtotime($a[1]));
        $t2 = max(strtotime($b[0]), strtotime($b[1]));
    
        return $t1 - $t2;
    }

usort($myArray, 'date_compare');
and not from db but from xmlrpc data